# jQuery fileuploader bluimp Error Not Found

Tags: php, jquery, upload

I will attempt to not be a "help vampire", as described in the article you reference on github. The jQuery fileuploader is quite spiffy and I want to use it.

Your uploader UI appears to work, but the back end part that writes the files to the actual server keeps giving me an error. Looking around the support forum, on Stack Overflow, and many other niches, I cannot find this very common problem addressed and solved.

The entire error from my server's error log is as follows:

Attempt to serve directory: /var/www/vhosts/md1network.com/httpdocs/user/profile/my-images/files/, referer: http://md1network.com/user/profile/my-images/

I have already made sure that my upload directory is writable, having set the permissions to 777.

Here is a screenshot of the web page and errors in the console:

[image: Screenshot]

I'm looking for any troubleshooting steps I can take.

I have temporarily removed the page protection from my source, so that ANYBODY can attempt to troubleshoot my error:

Here's the link:
http://md1network.com/user/profile/my-images/

Thanks.
Rick

Comment: It appears that this dir is not accesible via webbrowser http://md1network.com/user/profile/my-images/files/

Comment: The script is working fine...loading the pic but fails on place the pic on the selected dir...try using another upload dir...or chech that the apache user has perms over the upload dir...or give me ssh access to the server nd i can fix the problem xD(just kidding)

Comment: The permissions for the upload directory are set to 777. Doesn't that take care of permissions problems? The group is psacln [505] and the owner is admin_md1 [10003] which is pretty much a default install for Plesk.

Comment: When i try to enter to the upload dir via webbrowser, it gives me a download.html file instead of the index dir web view

Comment: Yes. There is no index there. There are no files in that directory whatsoever. The script should upload images into that directory. Please take a look at the documentation for the script: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One critical element that I just realized is the parts of the configuration.

In the main.js file, the part for the url is actually where the php script index.php lives. There should only be files in that directory - the index.php and UploadHandler.php.

The script will automatically create the files directory if it does not exist and therefore should have execute permissions and write permissions enabled on the php directory so that the files directory can be created.

main.js

```
    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    url: 'php/'
});
```

UploadHandler.php

```
        $this->options = array(
        'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/',
        'upload_dir' => dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/files/',
        'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/files/',
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the Error File Not Found issue after getting the uploader working yesterday. Turns out that if you disable the script below and your using the code out of the box, it ignores any options you set and attempts to upload to domain.com/your-path-/server/php

```
<!-- Bootstrap JS is not required, but included for the responsive demo navigation -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same behavior, and i figured out that the "upload" folder was getting htaccess rules from my root folder where i set specific rules i needed.

So i needed to somehow reset the rule in the whole upload directory.I created a new .htaccess file in my "upload" folder with the following:

RewriteEngine on

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This made it work right away!